# Powershell Get-WinEvent Truncates Message

Tags: powershell

I have the following Powershell code that counts the number of errors occurring per Provider, based on Error ID and Message.  What I am after is getting the count of each unique message per computer, log, provider, id and level.

However the issue that I'm having is that when I export this information to .csv the event message is being truncated.  Or rather, I'm not able to quite grasp what I need to do to get the entire event message.

Here is the code that grabs the event logs and exports it to .csv.

```
$computername = 'mycomputer'
$logs = "application", "system"

$info  = get-winevent -ComputerName $computername -FilterHashTable @{LogName=$logs; Level=1,2,3} | 
sort MachineName,LogName,ProviderName,{$_.LevelDisplayName},ID | 
Group MachineName, LogName, ProviderName, ID, {$_.LevelDisplayName}, Count, Message |
select @{N="Computer";E={$_.name.split(',')[0]}},@{N="Log";E={$_.name.split(',')[1]}}, @{N="Provider";E={$_.name.split(',')[2]}}, @{N="Error ID";E={$_.name.split(',')[3]}},`
@{N="Type";E={$_.name.split(',')[4]}}, count, @{N="Message";E={$_.name.split(',')[5 | 
Export-Csv -notypeinformation -Path c:\Test\events.csv
```

If I comment out

```
#| Export-Csv -notypeinformation -Path c:\Test\events.csv
```

And output

```
$info
```

I see the complete message.  I also can see more of the message if I continue to expand the array indexes.  For example I get more of the message if I do this:

```
, @{N="Message1";E={$_.name.split(',')[6]}}, @{N="Message2";E={$_.name.split(',')[7]}}
```

What do I need to code correct to get the entire message out in the

```
@{N="Message";E={$_.name.split(',')[5]}}
```

selection?

Answer (score 0):

I think you Can take a much easier approach, with the built-in `ConvertFrom-Csv`, Also the script would be much more Readable

```
$info  = get-winevent -ComputerName $computername -FilterHashTable @{LogName=$logs; Level=1,2,3} | 
sort MachineName,LogName,ProviderName,{$_.LevelDisplayName},ID | 
Group MachineName, LogName, ProviderName, ID, {$_.LevelDisplayName}, Count, Message

$Array = @()
$Header = "Computer","Log","Provider","ErrorID","Type","Message","Count"

Foreach ($item in $Info)
{
$Count = $Item.Count
$CSV = $item.Name | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "," -Header $Header
$CSV.Count = $Count
$Array += $CSV
}

$Array | Export-CSV C:\Test\Events.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I did try this but count is a read only property.

    'Count' is a ReadOnly property.
    At line:16 char:1
    + $CSV.Count = $Count

Comment: run on PS3 perfectly, will check it later anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're not truncating.  You've just got messages with commas in them, and Split() doesn't have any way to know what's a delimiter and what's part of the message.

Well, I suppose you could specify:

```
@{N="Message";E={($_.name.split(',')[5..($_.name.split(',').Count - 1)]) -join ','}}
```

But, honestly, this feels like some mighty gigantic hoops to jump through.

What's wrong with `$_.Group[0].<item>` instead of `$_.name.split(',')[<num>]`?  Except `count`, you're grouping by all the fields you're pulling, aren't you?  So the value on the first event should, by definition, be the same on every other event in the same group, right?

Also, why `{$_.LevelDisplayName}` instead of just `LevelDisplayName`?

And I think you'll find that Message won't work very well in a CSV unless you strip line feeds and carriage returns.

Try this:

```
$ComputerName = 'ComputerName';
$Logs = 'Application', 'System';

$Info = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $ComputerName -FilterHashTable @{LogName=$Logs; Level=1,2,3} `
    | Sort-Object MachineName, LogName, ProviderName, LevelDisplayName, ID `
    | Group-Object MachineName, LogName, ProviderName, ID, LevelDisplayName, Count, Message `
    | Select-Object @{N="Computer";E={$_.Group[0].MachineName}}, `
        @{N="Log";     E={$_.Group[0].LogName}}, `
        @{N="Provider";E={$_.Group[0].ProviderName}}, `
        @{N="Error ID";E={$_.Group[0].ID}}, `
        @{N="Type";    E={$_.Group[0].LevelDisplayName}}, `
        count, `
        @{N="Message"; E={$_.Group[0].Message.Replace("`r",' ').Replace("`n",' ')}} `
    | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path c:\Test\events.csv;
```

Comment: Thank you! Truncation was a poor word choice on my part, I wasn't sure how I should word it so I went with that.  There is nothing wrong with $_Group[0].<item> other than I wasn't aware of it.  Your suggestion works perfectly.  I have to use {$_.LevelDisplayName} instead of LevelDisplayName because it throws the following error if i don't.  

sort : Exception getting "LevelDisplayName": "The system cannot find the file specified"

You are correct on the group, I was just pounding this out without enough thought apparently.